# How to evaluate a string expression for multiple arguments?

Tags: r, string, parsing, eval

I have an api wrapper function that accepts custom arguments in addition to some defined parameters. For my use case this function needs to accept a variable size of custom arguments so I construct these arguments as a string expression with the documented operators for this api to be evaluated and passed; I don't have a reproducible example since this is such a customized function, but I'm hoping the concept can get us somewhere. I am having an issue with parsing these multiple arguments as constructed. So for example below is the original function call:

```
# original function
my_function(arg1 = this,
            arg2 = that,
            period = 12,
            # here are the two arguments that get passed in this case unique ids for specific data
            "0001q" %.d% c("1y", "2x", "3z"),
            "0002q" %.d% c("5u")
)

# my string expression
my_string <- "'0001q' %.d% c('1y', '2x', '3z'), '0002q' %.d% c('5u')"

# what I want to do
my_function(arg1 = this,
            arg2 = that,
            period = 12,
            # here are the two arguments that get passed in this case unique ids for specific data
            eval(parse(text = noquote(my_string)))
)
```

When I attempt the above I get the following error:

```
Error in parse(text = ... unexpected ','
```

I understand `parse` is expecting only one argument and in this case is getting two of them. Is there a way I can evaluate `my_string` using another function or a parse variant that will accept the multiple arguments?

Comment: Do you *need* to use string input? R has powerful metaprogramming capabilities, and for an API to accept strings rather than use metaprogramming is generally [a mistake](https://wiki.c2.com/?StringlyTyped). — Actually in your case it looks as if you simply need to use variable arguments (i.e. `...`) or a vector/list argument.

Comment: Unfortunately the way this api was made it seems this is the case that I need to pass a string input since the arguments can only be passed each as an id value followed by the operator and its subcategory ids.

Comment: It would really help if you had a concrete usage example, because I don’t understand what you mean by “the arguments can only be passed each as an id value followed by the operator and its subcategory ids.”

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). You seem to think the solution requires a string but that's rarely the case. Most likely using a list with `do.call` would be better. But since the problem is incomplete and not runnable, we can't really test any possible alternatives.

Comment: understood, actually the concept of using do.call may be applicable here. i will take a look at that. thanks